# Handling clicks on overlapping objects in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, overlap

I am building a very simple prototype of an [isometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry) game using `pygame`.

As I am really new to `pygame` and game development, I am not really sure how to handle clicking on multiple objects that have overlapping `rect`s. The game has tiles of dirt "stacked" in a way that they appear as a single block of land. The player should be able to click each tile independently.

Can you show me how to do this?

[image]

Comment: If you have a draw order, then you already have the reversed click precedence. In other words, if you click a stack of objects, the one drawn last (i.e. on top of everything else) would be the one you'd apply the click to. Does that help?

Comment: That is what I have tried so far, and it doesn't really work because I am checking collisions with rectangles wrapping each tile. So some rectangles overlap and, when I want to click a "previous" tile, I actually click the topmost rectangle first. I don't know if that is too confusing, hope I made it clear xD
What I could try is creating invisible polygons to match the exact shape of the superior part of each dirt tile and check collisions with each of these surfaces...

Comment: That's a good point, if an object is not square and you click a transparent part of it, which is still within the rect, then that wouldn't work. Seems like the polygon idea would be an alternative to reading the transparency of the pixel the user clicked on, or something odd like that.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is pretty simple:

You store all the draggable objects in a list. Whenever a click is detected on an object:

1. Find the list index of that object.
2. Check if any other objects in the list, with index greater than the current object *(which means that they are drawn above the current object)*, are selected.
   If so, don't call the `drag` function, and if not, do call it.
3. Right before we call the function, make sure to reposition the list index of the current object; since we just clicked it, it should be above all other objects,
   so `remove` the object from the list, and `append` it to the end.

Here is an implementation of the concept:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

objs = []

class Obj:
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, color):
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.dragging = False
        self.color = color
        objs.append(self)

    def clicked(self, m_pos):
        return self.rect.collidepoint(m_pos)

    def set_offset(self, m_pos):
        self.dragging = True
        m_x, m_y = m_pos
        self.offset_x = self.rect.x - m_x
        self.offset_y = self.rect.y - m_y

    def drag(self, m_pos):
        m_x, m_y = m_pos
        self.rect.x = m_x + self.offset_x
        self.rect.y = m_y + self.offset_y

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect)

square1 = Obj(200, 170, 100, 100, (255, 0, 0))
square2 = Obj(150, 300, 100, 100, (0, 255, 0))
square3 = Obj(220, 30, 100, 100, (0, 0, 255))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                for square in objs:
                    if square.clicked(event.pos):
                        o = objs[objs.index(square)+1:]
                        if not any(s.clicked(event.pos) for s in o):
                            objs.remove(square)
                            objs.append(square)
                            square.set_offset(event.pos)
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if event.button == 1:
                for square in objs:
                    square.dragging = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            for square in objs:
                if square.dragging:
                    square.drag(event.pos)
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for square in objs:
        square.draw()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @RandomDavis That is not a problem for the `pygame.Rect().collidepoint()` method.